# Laravel Collections :multidimensional array, Group by keys and unique values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How would one do the following with [laravel collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections)

We got this array : Let's assume we don't know the multi keys in advance

```
$input =[
            ['name' =>'John McClane','age'=>'40' ],
            ['name' =>'John McClane','age'=>'50' ],
            ['name' =>'Hans Gruber','age'=>'40' ],
            ['name' =>'Hans Gruber','age'=>'50' ],
            ['name' =>'Holly McClane','age'=>'20' ],
            ['name' =>'Holly McClane','age'=>'49' ],
        ];


$output =[
            'name' => [
                'John McClane',
                'Hans Gruber',
                'Holly McClane'
            ],
            'age' =>[
                '40',
                '50',
                '20',
                '49'
            ]
        ];
```

**Update** : @Felippe Duarte  added the PHP plain version on how one would do it.

```
 $output =[];
 foreach($input as $arr){
            $keys = array_keys($arr);
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                $output[$key] =  array_unique(array_column($input, $key));
            }
        }
```

Just replacing `array_unique(array_column($input, $key));`
with `$input->pluck($key)->toArray();`  is not very interesting.

What I am wondering , is there a neat way to this entirely with a laravel collection in a single line?

Group by multidimensional keys, with unique values.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

With plain PHP you can use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$output = [
    'name' => array_unique(array_column($input, 'name')),
    'age' => array_unique(array_column($input, 'age')),
];
```

With collection you can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck) and [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-unique):

```
$output = [
    'name' => $input->pluck('name')->unique(),
    'age' => $input->pluck('age')->unique(),
];
```

If you don't know the keys, use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) or [keys()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-keys), get the keys then repeat the above process:

```
$keys = array_keys($input); //$input->keys();

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $output[$key] = $input->pluck($key)->unique();
}
```

Comment: Yes , that makes a lot of sens Felippe , thanks..  I edited my post after your reply.  What if you don't know the keys.  But I got the idea. Thanks mate

Comment: Thanks Felippe , but I got that with plain php.   Apart for using pluck and unique.  I was wondering If there was a method in laravel to create this in one line.  $collection->groupBy(something)->unique(something). But thanks for your time